# Optimization (bin packing?)

Tags: python, r, optimization, pandas

I have some containers that contain items of particular type and some operations are executed on  them:

```
container_id item_type no_of_items operation1_executions operation2_executions
         600         1         500                   400                   300
         700         1         200                   600                   600
         600         2         400                   200                   900
```

The goal is to balance `no_of_items`, `operation1_executions` and `operation2_executions` per container as close to each other for each container as possible. Obviously, each container can hold a maximum number of items, and operation executions have cost (growing with `log` of number of items).

The catch: the only operation available is moving a specified number of items of particular type from a specified source container to a specified target container. That is, apart from item type, items can not be individually selected (they're randomly selected).

What's the optimum/reasonable solution here? Linear regression of some sort? Some heuristical "goodness fit" function?

(a solution that makes use of pandas/SciKit would be preferable, if somebody thinks of smth more than "pure" algorithm)

UPDATE: Josilber is correct in pointing out that "as close as possible to each other" is a hazy objective.

The trouble is that it is precisely balancing container loads as to minimize overall load imposed by `operation1 .. operationN` is what I'm after and that pattern is unknown. I'm not even sure what weight/cost, if any, to attach to an `operation` of particular type.

This is not a theoretical problem, it's a twisted and complicated problem I encountered in production.

Using a simplistic assumption of weight/cost of 1 in each operation, regardless of operation type, would be good enough for starters. So I guess I would seek minimizing sum vector in following matrix:

```
(container 1)  [sum(oper1 cost .. operN cost)]   [no of item_type1, no of item_type2, ... item_typeL]
(container 2)  [sum(oper1 cost .. operN cost)]   [no of item_type1, no of item_type2, ... item_typeL]
.                                              = 
.
(container M)  [sum(oper1 cost .. operN cost)]   [no of item_type1, no of item_type2, ... item_typeL]
```

That's only first and rough approximation, of course. If I minimized the left-hand sum cost vector but say oper5 cost (execution time) in some container started to rise excessively, that would be unacceptable. However, I need to start somewhere with solving this problem and this point seems as good as any.

Comment: This is an optimization problem. I think the first step would mathematically defining your objective (aka exactly what you mean by "as close to each other for each container as possible" and how that is balanced against the operation execution costs) and your constraints. Could you give the objective value associated with a few feasible solutions and give an example of an infeasible solution? There are optimization tools available in many languages, but you'll need to be able to specify your problem mathematically to use them.